# Passing an Enum member to constructor: "actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Tags: java, constructor, enums

I'm  puzzled, I assume I'm doing something quite stupid, I just can't see it!

Central heating control:

A **Radiator** class and a **RadiatorSize** class. Radiator has a size instance variable, which is of Class RadiatorSize. I have XSMALL, ... XLARGE for sizes of radiators; defined as public enum in RadiatorSize.

So, I'm thinking, create a new Radiator and give it a MEDIUM size.

```
size = new RadiatorSize(RadiatorSize.Size.MEDIUM);
```

Netbeans tells me this:

```
...\CentralHeating\src\hardwaremodel\Radiator.java:17:
error: constructor RadiatorSize in class RadiatorSize cannot be
applied to given types;

size = new RadiatorSize(RadiatorSize.Size.MEDIUM);
required: no arguments
found: Size
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Here are the offending classes.

```
/** Radiator class **/
package hardwaremodel;

import units_constants.RadiatorSize;

public class Radiator {
    private int boilerSequence;
    private RadiatorSize size;
    private double volume; //cubic centimetres

public void Radiator(int blrSqnc) {
    boilerSequence = blrSqnc;
    size = new RadiatorSize(RadiatorSize.Size.MEDIUM); //ERROR HERE
    }
}


/** RadiatorSize class **/
package units_constants;

public class RadiatorSize {
    public enum Size {XSMALL, SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, XLARGE};

    private Size size;

    public void RadiatorSize(Size sz) {
        size = sz;
    }
}
```

Now, Netbeans gives me a hint, it suggests "Create Constructor RadiatorSize(units_constants.RadiatorSize.Size) in units_constants.RadiatorSize"; which it does when I agree:

```
public RadiatorSize(Size size) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

Now there are now no little red circles in the Editor, but what the ...!

I'm puzzled.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've done the same mistake twice! I've given my "constructors" in both these classes return types! Which of course means they are not constructors!

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to use this as constructor:

```
public void RadiatorSize(Size sz) {
        size = sz;
}
```

Because this is not a constructor, but a `void` method, your `new RadiatorSize(Size.MEDIUM);` tries to call the standard constructor, which has no parameters. Knowing this, the error message given makes total sense ;)

Just get rid of the `void` return type and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you guys! I blame (racing drivers style excuses coming up) being tired after a Windows crash, losing 5 days work on this, and being very hung over - still - from a party two days ago!

Answer (score 3):

Constructors dont have return types not even void.

```
public void RadiatorSize(Size sz) {
        size = sz;
    }
```

is a method not a constructor.

```
public  RadiatorSize(Size sz) {
        size = sz;
    }
```

now this is a constructor

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
public void RadiatorSize(Size sz) {
    size = sz;
}
```

Is not a constructor, it's a method. You specified `void` as your return type. Just take a look at what Netbeans generated:

```
public RadiatorSize(Size size) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

Notice the lack of the `void` return type here?

Comment: @HarryAlffa Happens to everyone :)

Comment: No worries - you'd think you'd spot it after copying, pasting, editing! But that is not how being stupid works! :)

Answer (score 1):

as far as I saw, you don't have the constructor at all.

```
public void RadiatorSize(Size sz) {
        size = sz;
    }
```

is **not** constructor, it is normal method.

try to change it into:

```
 public RadiatorSize RadiatorSize(Size sz) {
            size = sz;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need constructors in Radiator and RadiatorSize. The methods that LOOK like constructors actually have a return type and are treated as regular methods. Take the return type off.